# Registering region with registerRegionWithCircularOverlay Method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm able to get my Current Location using CoreLocation framework. I want to register my current location so that i want to know who has entered and exited the region. For that i have used apple documented method to register a region which is `- (void)registerRegionWithCircularOverlay:(MKCircle*)overlay andIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier { }` . My question is when does this method gets called?

document link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Any help?

Comment: I think that's a custom method, and you'll get others methods to trigger with the last line of this method. And you check it when your didEnterRegion.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to take care of permission to access location of user device. So that application is able to track user location.

You can do this by following:

1. Add a key `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in a .plist file. This is key has a value of type `String`. You must take care don't use other than `String` type here.

[image]

2. Ask user to before access to user location, add below line.

   ```
   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   self.locationManager.delegate = self;
   [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
   ```
3. Below code will start monitoring region:

   ```
   // Tell location manager to start monitoring for the region
   [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
   ```

Also override below methods to make sure that region is discovered:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    // We entered a region!
    NSLog(@"Entered in region");
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    // Exited the region
    NSLog(@"Exited from region");
}
```

Comment: I have done everything u mentioned above checking authorization permission , description of permission in Plist etc I m trying to register a region with above said method and followed all apple guidelines inside it like checking isMonitoringAvailable and is authorized but On which coreLocation delegate event I should call this method before posting the question I was thinking it gets called on some location change

Comment: You can perfectly do that, I mean registering user location in a delegate method `didEnterRegion:`. And here you have to put a check that user can not register twice.